# MongoDB transactions

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB. I am trying to learn Transactions. I am trying to add a record inside a transaction. I am throwing an error inside transaction. Here is my code

```
await client.connect()
console.table('.....connected');
const session = client.startSession()
console.log('...session started');
await session.withTransaction(async () => {
console.log('.....Promise started')
const db: Db = client.db('sample_mflix')
movieCollection = db.collection('movies');
movieCollection.insertOne({ abc: 11 })
new Error('error occured')
then((res) => {
            console.log('.....inserted')
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log('...error', err);
        }).finally(async () => {
            console.log('...session ended')
            session.endSession()
        })
```

But even on error throwing record is being saved in database. But it should not. What shall I do make my transaction ACID.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the created sessions to do write operations. Instead of

```
movieCollection = db.collection('movies');
```

Try

```
movieCollection = session.getDatabase("'sample_mflix'").movies;
```

Then you have to start the transaction and write data

```
session.startTransaction();
movieCollection.insertOne({ abc: 11 });
```

This should now rollback the changes committed, when you call `endSession()` as it would trigger to abort any open transactions.

Also see: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Session/ and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/

Comment: Then what is the purpose of withTransaction method.

Comment: You can use `withTransaction` but still you have to pass in the session object to write operations `movieCollection.insertOne({ abc: 11 }, { session })`